# How can Inspect the error queue from Rebus

Tags: rebus

I have a input queue which runs fine.  Sometimes a message gets on the error queue. 
Now i want to be able inspect these messages and maybe forward them to the input queue again if I know this particular message will pass.

How do I start with inspecting the error queue?  Are there any best practices?
I can't just do a `.CreateBus().Start()` because this will trigger the handlers from the normal handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you inspect queues and the options you get depends on the chosen transport.

*If you're using Rebus with MSMQ*, the easiest way to inspect your queues (input queues, error queues, MSMS dead-letter queues) and retry delivery of failed messages is to fire up [Rebus Snoop](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Snoop). Rebus has a [ReturnToSourceQueue CLI tool for MSMQ](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/Rebus.Forklift.Msmq) as well.

*If you're using Azure Service Bus*, I can recommend [Paolo Salvatori's Service Bus Explorer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/service-bus-explorer-f2abca5a) which I've used a little bit myself on a few projects.

*With RabbitMQ*, I usually use RabbitMQ's built-in web management plugin to inspect queues, and then Rebus comes with a [ReturnToSourceQueue CLI tool for RabbitMQ](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/Rebus.Forklift.RabbitMq) as well.

*If you're using SQL Server*, I can recommend firing up SQL Server Management Studio and getting your SQL-fu on ;)

If you want to code something that does some kind of automatic forwarding or handling of failed messages, I can recommend using Rebus' transport implementations (i.e. `MsmsMessageQueue` (along with `MsmqUtil`), `RabbitMqMessageQueue`, `AzureServiceBusMessageQueue`, etc.) to handle the receiving and sending of raw transport messages - it's an approach that I've used several times myself to e.g. implement crude second level retries mechanisms and forwarding and archival of failed messages etc.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I use azure servicebus.  Sorry!  Had no clue this would make inpact on the approach.

Comment: I've expanded the answer accordingly :)

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried the Service Bus Explorer.  But Rebus didn't liked the move.  Can the message moved 'as is' to the input queue?

Comment: I don't remember having any trouble doing that - what do you mean that "Rebus doesn't like the move"?

Comment: I clicked "repair an resubmit" and my rebus handler went nuts :-)  I'll try it again on Monday and keep you posted.

Comment: This is the message throw by rebus:  Rebus.Bus.Worker WARN (Rebus 1 worker 1): Caught an exception when interacting with the queue system - there's basically no meaningful work we can do as long as
 we can't successfully commit a queue transaction, so instead we wait and hope that the situation gets better... current wait time is 00:00:30 -- seems that the error messages are not the same (and contain the exception).  A simple move is not the best idea.

Comment: Had not everything wired up correctly.  Everything works.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mookid8000 Is there a new way of returning the message to the source queue when using RabbitMQ now?

Comment: I have a customer where we have [the Shovel plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) installed – it can be used to forward all messages to a specific queue, but it doesn't really offer anything like "Return to source queue", which would be more useful. If you're interested in one-upping your tooling, you might also want to take a look at [Fleet Manager](https://rebus.fm/services/fleet-manager/), which completely replaces the need for dead-letter queues and allows for inspecting the contents of each message, returning to source queues, filtering, etc.